# Traverse HDF5 file/tree and continue after return?

Tags: python, numpy, tree, h5py

I have a HDF5 file that contains some sort of tree structure:

```
/a_1
/a_1/b_1
/a_1/b_1/data
/a_1
/a_1/b_2
/a_1/b_2/data
/a_2
/a_2/b_1
/a_2/b_1/data
/a_2
/a_2/b_2
/a_2/b_2/data
```

Here `/a_X/b_X` are groups and one can assume that the DataSet `data` 
 contains some sort of numerical data. What is the best way to extract `data`? Naturally, I would try:

```
def extract(name, node):
    if isinstance(node, hdf.Dataset):
        return node[...]
    return None

with h5py.File(some_file) as f:
    f.visititems(extract)
```

but this stops after something other than `None` is returned for the first time. Of course, one could build a global object and append but I'm wondering if there is some sort of 'best practice' for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever fits your overall script structure.  You might get hints in the file/directory walking code.

So with one of my test files, a simple print function would produce:

```
def foo(name, obj):
   print(name, obj)
   return None

In [203]: f.visititems(foo)
Mcoo <HDF5 group "/Mcoo" (3 members)>
Mcoo/col <HDF5 dataset "col": shape (20,), type "<i4">
Mcoo/data <HDF5 dataset "data": shape (20,), type "<f8">
Mcoo/row <HDF5 dataset "row": shape (20,), type "<i4">
Mcsr <HDF5 group "/Mcsr" (3 members)>
Mcsr/data <HDF5 dataset "data": shape (20,), type "<f8">
Mcsr/indices <HDF5 dataset "indices": shape (20,), type "<i4">
Mcsr/indptr <HDF5 dataset "indptr": shape (11,), type "<i4">
```

I suspect that's one of the more common usages - just a way of quickly exploring the data structure.  To fetch a particular `dataset` we'd normally use a fully qualified name.  Or iterate on several levels of keys.

```
In [207]: f['Mcoo/row']
Out[207]: <HDF5 dataset "row": shape (20,), type "<i4">
```

As you note, and as documented, if the function attempts to return the found object, it quits.

```
def extract(name, node):
    if isinstance(node, h5py.Dataset):
        return node[...]
    return None
In [211]: x=f.visititems(extract)
In [212]: x
Out[212]: array([0, 6, 8, 9, 4, 6, 9, 0, 1, 8, 9, 1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 6, 0, 4, 6])
```

We could collect the items in a dictionary (global or belonging to some object):

```
def extract(name, node):
    if isinstance(node, h5py.Dataset):
        dd[name] = node[...]
    return None

In [214]: dd = {}
In [215]: f.visititems(extract)
In [217]: list(dd.keys())
Out[217]: 
['Mcoo/col',
 'Mcsr/data',
 ...
 'Mcoo/row']
```

But the file itself can be accessed as a dictionary, so this might not add much, except to maybe flatten the nesting.

Or as a list of values, or list of tuples of name and value, etc

A simple class:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.sets = []
    def __call__(self, name, node):
        if isinstance(node, h5py.Dataset):
            self.sets.append(node)
        return None

In [227]: M = MyClass()
In [228]: f.visititems(M)
In [229]: M.sets
Out[229]: 
[<HDF5 dataset "col": shape (20,), type "<i4">,
 <HDF5 dataset "data": shape (20,), type "<f8">,
 ... 
 <HDF5 dataset "indptr": shape (11,), type "<i4">]
```

Comment: Thanks for some help here, I guess the approach with a class makes sense in my case - I'll check it out ;)